# Почему тут может вылетать программа?

Tags: c++, android, сокет

Если отправляю на обычный компьютер, то норм, а если на Android - то вылетает...

```
bool Socket::sendAll(void *buffer, int size) {
  if (!isValid()) return 0;
  char *ptr = (char*) buffer;

  int counter = 0;
  while (size > 0)
  {

// Иногда вот в это строчке вылетает, если отправляю на Android:
int sz = ::send(m_sock, ptr, size, 0);

    usleep(1000);
    if (sz < 1) {
      counter++;
      if (counter > 10000) return false;
      continue;
    }
    ptr += sz;
    size -= sz;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: А из чего следует, что вылет именно на этом фрагменте? Что видно под отладчиком?

Comment: да, отладчиком...

Comment: ну так если дошли до вылета в отладчике, то в чём проблема установить точное место и причину?

Comment: вылетает здесь, хотя должно работать int sz = ::send(m_sock, ptr, size, 0);

Answer (score 2):

Вы точно понимаете, что происходит, если send возвратил отрицательное число? Например, вполне мог произойти обрыв связи. То есть, физически передать данные нельзя. И на фоне этого код вида

```
counter++;
if (counter > 10000) return false;
```

выглядит немного дико. Вряд ли что то сильно поменяется. Если только у Вас в отдельном потоке не происходит автоматическое переподключение (что уже чревато ошибками) или сокеты udp (но судя по коду, это не так).

В целом - send вернул отрицательное число - сокет закрыли, ошибку распечатали и все, никаких "я ещё 9999 раз попытаюсь потыкать мертвый сокет".

Comment: Отправил данные первый раз - улетело сколько то байт... второй раз пробую - выдаёт всегда -1... но через какое-то время опять может отправить...

Comment: если произошла ошибка (возвратило -1), то нужно распечатать текст ошибки и посмотреть, что там.

char *p = strerr(errno);
 fprintf(stderr," Error (%d): %s occured\n", errno, p);

Comment: EAGAIN = 11 //Try arain ... вроде как попробывать заново...

Comment: да, в этом случае нужно действительно попробовать ещё раз. Но в Вашем коде  нет обработки подобной ситуации.

Comment: int sz = ::send(m_sock, ptr, size, 0); здесь вылетает... например, раз на 10-ый

Comment: вылетает потому, что сокет был закрыт, но это не было корректно обработано и в этот сокет дальше пишутся данные. Но система то в курсе, что сокет закрыт и рубит приложение.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24432/discussion-between-sitev-ru-and-kovadim).

Comment: strace хорошая штука оказывается - показал мне, что отсылался сигнал SIGPIPE, теперь, если в send указываю флаг MSG_NOSIGNAL, то всё работает, как надо и не вылетает...

Comment: Собственно о чем я и говорил с самого начала. Я надеюсь, код теперь переписан как положено?

Comment: С разных "сотиков" подключаюсь... Где-то прокатывает, а где-то выдаёт ошибку 104

Comment: 104 это "Connection reset by peer" (то  есть телефоном). А вот почему он это решил - мало чего, сеть отвалилась, человек в подвал зашел.

Comment: Попробую переписать отправку с помощью epoll, как я понимаю, должно всё заработать...